# Extract only one specific table from a compressed Postgres sql dump

Tags: postgresql

I have a big posgresql compressed dump from which I need to extract the data from one table. The compressed posgresql dump is 25G and if I uncompress it it will become 300GB sql file. Need help to get data about one particular table without uncompressing the dump. is it possible?

Comment: What format of dump is it?  plain, custom, tar, directory.  Do you need the entire definition, indexes, etc., or just the data?

Comment: I need entire definition , index for that table. This is the compressed file "databaseaida.sql.gz " . when I try to use pg_restore , I get error pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql. I tried using this way - gunzip <  /databaseaida.sql.gz | pg_restore -d tempo1 --table="bigram_counts" -v -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is a plain format dump, you can use perl (or sed or awk or ...) to pull out the data section for one table.  The `..` operator says where to start, and where to stop.

```
zcat dump.sql.gz | perl -ne 'print if /^COPY public.pgbench_accounts/ .. /^\\\.$/'| pgbench_accounts.sql
```

It is possible that this will lead to false matches in weird/malicious circumstances, like if the string 'COPY public.pgbench_accounts' were to occur as a value in the first column of some table.

To get the non-data part of the table definition, I would just use nearly the reverse of the above to strip out all of the data and get just the definitions (of all objects, not just one), which should generate a small enough file to be edited by hand to pull out just the one you want.

```
zcat dump.sql.gz | perl -lne 'print if not /^COPY /../^\\\.$/' > edit_me.sql
```

If you don't like the manual work, you could push just the definition-only part through psql into some dummy database, then redump out just the table you want.

```
createdb foobar
zcat dump.sql.gz | perl -lne 'print if not /^COPY /../^\\\.$/' | psql foobar
pg_dump foobar -t pgbench_accounts > pgbench_accounts.def.sql
```

You might want to dump pre-data and post-data sections separately, so you can populate the table before creating indexes.  Again, this is subject getting confused by weird/malicious content.

Comment: Thank you so much ! This helped me to extract table information.